# Not able to apply validation on my custom checkout step

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, form-validation

I am trying to apply validation on my custom checkout step field but not able to do it..i want to use magento by default validations ..below is the code attached..

**my-step-view.js**

```
 define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function (ko, Component, _, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
     * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of your module directory.
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: '<vendor_module>/mystep'
        },

        // add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                // step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'step_code',
                // step alias
                null,
                // step title value
                'Custom Step',
                // observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                15
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout steps
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         * When the user navigates to the custom step via url anchor or back button we_must show step manually here
         */
        navigate: function () {
            this.isVisible(true);
        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
});
```

**mystep.html**

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="step_code" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <input type="tel" class="input-text required-entry" name="custom" id="">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
....
            <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/view/my-step-view</item>

                                            <!-- Validations -->

                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                            </item>



                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>

                                    </item>
                                </item>
....
```

Comment: Add your validation on navigateToNextStep method before passing to next step

Comment: can you please provide me a code solution as i am a beginner..i need a validation for required field..@SohelRana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste below code in **checkout_index_index.xml**
In the below code we have created a template for the form and placed it as the children of new step we created.

```
<item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/view/form</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ustom-checkout-form-container</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/form</item>
    </item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
           <item name="displayArea"
                xsi:type="string">
                custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="text_field" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract<item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">                      customCheckoutForm</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.text_field</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Text Field</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

**form.js**

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'ko',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function (ko,Component, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            
            return this;
        },
        /**
         * Form submit handler
         *
         * This method can have any name.
         */

        onSubmit: function () {
            // trigger form validation
            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.source.trigger('customCheckoutForm.data.validate');
            // verify that form data is valid

            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                
                // do something with form data
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**form.html**

```
<div>
    <form id="custom-checkout-form" class="form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-fields') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </fieldset>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: onSubmit" class="action">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Submit'"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```